# A problem about Green's theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $p(x,y),q(x,y)\in C^1(B_r(0)),B_r(0)=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le r^2\}$,show that:
$$
\int_{B_r(0)} (p_xq_y-p_yq_x) dxdy=\int_{\partial B_r(0)} p\frac{\partial q}{\partial s}ds
$$
I want use the Green's theorem:
$$
\int_{\Omega} (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dxdy=\int_{\partial \Omega} Pdx+Qdy
$$
However, I couldn't go on becauseI couldn't piece together the two

Comment: Isn't the rightmost line integral in the 4th line the definition of the rightmost integral in the second line?